# Codemirror autocomplete - suggestions sources

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using codemirror autocomplete demo. It shows some javascript keywords such as application cache,defaultStatus and framenet and many more suggestions.  I want it to display my keywords as suggestions. But i am not able to find the source from which these javascript keywords are coming. Please help me with this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript mode was very hard to understand. so I took python mode and changing python-hint.js was very easy and i got output what i wanted. Thanks Eliran..

Comment: sure, great thought simplifying the process, way to go on the initiative.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`javascript-hint.js`](http://codemirror.net/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js), which contains some keywords, as can be seen in the source. e.g. the javascript keywords (line 96):

```
var javascriptKeywords = 
    ("break case catch continue debugger default delete do else false finally for function " +
     "if in instanceof new null return switch throw true try typeof var void while with")
    .split(" ");
```

That should get you started on writing your own `*-hint.js` file.

Comment: Actually these are only few keywords of them , Many of the other keywords are not there into this file.

Comment: well, i did say *That should get you started on...*. it's just a matter of going through the demo code. **Use the source, luke!**

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking through older CodeMirror autocomplete questions before asking a question of my own when I came across this.

The Javascript completions come from a combination of sources and you can see this in the source as Eliran has pointed out [javascript-hint.js](https://codemirror.net/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js).

This is the relevant function at this time:

```
    function getCompletions(token, context, keywords, options) {
    var found = [], start = token.string, global = options && options.globalScope || window;
    function maybeAdd(str) {
      if (str.lastIndexOf(start, 0) == 0 && !arrayContains(found, str)) found.push(str);
    }
    function gatherCompletions(obj) {
      if (typeof obj == "string") forEach(stringProps, maybeAdd);
      else if (obj instanceof Array) forEach(arrayProps, maybeAdd);
      else if (obj instanceof Function) forEach(funcProps, maybeAdd);
      for (var name in obj) maybeAdd(name);
    }

    if (context && context.length) {
      // If this is a property, see if it belongs to some object we can
      // find in the current environment.
      var obj = context.pop(), base;
      if (obj.type && obj.type.indexOf("variable") === 0) {
        if (options && options.additionalContext)
          base = options.additionalContext[obj.string];
        if (!options || options.useGlobalScope !== false)
          base = base || global[obj.string];
      } else if (obj.type == "string") {
        base = "";
      } else if (obj.type == "atom") {
        base = 1;
      } else if (obj.type == "function") {
        if (global.jQuery != null && (obj.string == '$' || obj.string == 'jQuery') &&
            (typeof global.jQuery == 'function'))
          base = global.jQuery();
        else if (global._ != null && (obj.string == '_') && (typeof global._ == 'function'))
          base = global._();
      }
      while (base != null && context.length)
        base = base[context.pop().string];
      if (base != null) gatherCompletions(base);
    } else {
      // If not, just look in the global object and any local scope
      // (reading into JS mode internals to get at the local and global variables)
      for (var v = token.state.localVars; v; v = v.next) maybeAdd(v.name);
      for (var v = token.state.globalVars; v; v = v.next) maybeAdd(v.name);
      if (!options || options.useGlobalScope !== false)
        gatherCompletions(global);
      forEach(keywords, maybeAdd);
    }
    return found;
  }
```

Here you can see a few sources.  **keywords** is a parameter provided by the calling function (not shown) and in this case it was the split string Eliran mentioned:

```
 var javascriptKeywords = ("break case catch continue debugger default delete do else false finally for function " +
              "if in instanceof new null return switch throw true try typeof var void while with").split(" ");
```

Then there is a branch in the logic here: `if (context && context.length) {`

In the true case it uses the context object passed by the caller (in this case a chain of properties).  It can use an optional **additionalContext** object or if useGlobalScope was not explicitly disabled in the options it can use the **global** object as a base to start the lookup (string, atom, and function types have special handling logic).  It then uses a while loop to resolve the context chain and call `gatherCompletions`.  Based on the type of the object passed to `gatherCompletions` it can try to add the other hard coded lists provided by the **split strings**:

```
  var stringProps = ("charAt charCodeAt indexOf lastIndexOf substring substr slice trim trimLeft trimRight " +
                     "toUpperCase toLowerCase split concat match replace search").split(" ");
  var arrayProps = ("length concat join splice push pop shift unshift slice reverse sort indexOf " +
                    "lastIndexOf every some filter forEach map reduce reduceRight ").split(" ");
  var funcProps = "prototype apply call bind".split(" ");
```

Or by iterating the properties of the javascript object itself.

Finally in the else case `token.state.localVars`, `token.state.globalVars`, and again if not explicitly disabled the **global** object is used as the object to the `gatherCompletions` function.  This is where you will also note the keywords as mentioned above.  Note that global is either provided in the `options.globalScope` or it assumes the value of window.

## Summary

Just to quickly show all of the sources here:

1. javascriptKeywords
2. funcProps
3. arrayProps
4. stringProps
5. global object
6. options.additionalContext
7. token.state.localVars
8. token.state.globalVars
9. context properties chain

Comment: What exactly is `options`?

Comment: I don't think they are all documented, but you can have a look [here](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config).  In this case the "additionalContext" is implied in the code above: `base = options.additionalContext[obj.string];`.  I don't recall off the top of my head what `obj.string` values would be, but you could set a break and inspect it.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't inspect it because the whole function does not have any options in it. I can't even find the word once in both python-hint.js and show-hint.js

Comment: You must manually specify options.  You should see them as a param to [showHint](https://codemirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.js) (the third param in the current version in the previous link).  More information is also provided in the [manual](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint).  Many of the options available are not documented so you have to look for implied values in the code.

Answer (score -1):

This really works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>CodeMirror</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="UTF-8">
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://CodeMirror.net/doc/docs.css">
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/anyword-hint.js" id="anyword"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/dialog/dialog.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.css">
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/sql-hint.js"></script>
 <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/mode/loadmode.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/meta.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/xml-hint.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/html-hint.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/jump-to-line.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/dialog/dialog.js"></script> 
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/searchcursor.js"></script>
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/jump-to-line.js"></script> 
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/search.js"></script> 
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/scroll/annotatescrollbar.js"></script> 
<script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor" onclick="autocomplete()"></div>
<script>
    function autocomplete() {
        
        myCodeMirror.execCommand("autocomplete");
    }
</script>
<script>
   var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(
   document.getElementById('editor'), {
      lineNumbers: true,
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```